# Caurina Action Script Error

Tags: flash, actionscript, flash-cs4, tween

I've seen an very simple and nice flash "selection of color combination" here

http://activeden.net/item/dark-light-portfolio-template/full_screen_preview/104152

(the choosing of template style was my aim)

Now i've tried to recreate the flash using caurina tweener class

but now i'm getting errors not in my script but in caurina script tweener.as

here is the project file of what i have recreated

http://www.mediafire.com/?7s74o86y81oi2mj

I have tried to tweak the compile errors(mostly syntax errors)...but  in vain

Pls help me what was the mistake i made

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check your tweener class with the code at http://code.google.com/p/tweener/downloads/detail?name=tweener_1_33_74_as2.zip&can=2&q=